# Adjusting table size for the text to fit

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I am a bit puzzle, I am simply trying to fit the text in the table but latex doesn't see to comply to that and put the text over two rows.

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\small
\caption[Atrial segmentation: dataset LA regions score table]{Metrics score table for the different regions of the LA using LA cavity-endocardium labels. Abbreviations: LA, left atrium; MSD, mean surface distance; PV, pulmonary veins.}\label{endo_analysis_table}
\begin{tabular}[h!]{ l c c c c }
\toprule
 Metrics & Overall & Mitral valve region & LA central region & PV region & LA roof\\
 &  & (0-20\%) & (20-65\%) & (65-85\%) & (85-100\%)\\
\midrule
Dice score      & 93.77 $\pm$0.17 & 88.38 $\pm$7.3 & 96.01 $\pm$1.43 & 89.60 $\pm$5.15 & 78.75 $\pm$12.13\\
Jacquard Index  & 88.32 $\pm$0.3  & 80.41 $\pm$10.02 & 92.37 $\pm$2.59 & 81.77 $\pm$7.74 & 66.93 $\pm$14.82\\
MSD             & 0.613 $\pm$0.02 & 1.534 $\pm$1.01 & 0.875 $\pm$0.37 & 1.571 $\pm$1.17 & 1.841 $\pm$1.44\\
Sensibility     & 93.87 $\pm$0.03 & 89 $\pm$11.74 & 95.78 $\pm$2.68 & 90.78 $\pm$7.52 & 83.85 $\pm$15.63\\
Specificity     & 99.70 $\pm$0.002 & 99.61 $\pm$0.44 & 99.59 $\pm$0.27 & 99.36 $\pm$0.49 & 99.65 $\pm$0.41\\
Diameter error  & 3.277 $\pm$1.1 & 11.31 $\pm$9.42 & 2.81 $\pm$2.76 & 9.37 $\pm$9.79 & 22.15 $\pm$24.88\\
Volume error    & 4.285 $\pm$0.6 & 15.75 $\pm$13.67 & 3.51 $\pm$2.74 & 11.96 $\pm$11.03 & 35.65 $\pm$40.28\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Resulting in that: [image: table result]

I don't understand as it seems there is some room to put the columns header on 1 row !

Is there a way to control it or adjust it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `c` that is missing in your code inside the `tabular` definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\small
\caption[Atrial segmentation: dataset LA regions score table]{Metrics score table for the different regions of the LA using LA cavity-endocardium labels. Abbreviations: LA, left atrium; MSD, mean surface distance; PV, pulmonary veins.}\label{endo_analysis_table}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
 Metrics & Overall & Mitral valve region & LA central region & PV region & LA roof\\
 &  & (0-20\%) & (20-65\%) & (65-85\%) & (85-100\%)\\
\midrule
Dice score      & 93.77 $\pm$0.17 & 88.38 $\pm$7.3 & 96.01 $\pm$1.43 & 89.60 $\pm$5.15 & 78.75 $\pm$12.13\\
Jacquard Index  & 88.32 $\pm$0.3  & 80.41 $\pm$10.02 & 92.37 $\pm$2.59 & 81.77 $\pm$7.74 & 66.93 $\pm$14.82\\
MSD             & 0.613 $\pm$0.02 & 1.534 $\pm$1.01 & 0.875 $\pm$0.37 & 1.571 $\pm$1.17 & 1.841 $\pm$1.44\\
Sensibility     & 93.87 $\pm$0.03 & 89 $\pm$11.74 & 95.78 $\pm$2.68 & 90.78 $\pm$7.52 & 83.85 $\pm$15.63\\
Specificity     & 99.70 $\pm$0.002 & 99.61 $\pm$0.44 & 99.59 $\pm$0.27 & 99.36 $\pm$0.49 & 99.65 $\pm$0.41\\
Diameter error  & 3.277 $\pm$1.1 & 11.31 $\pm$9.42 & 2.81 $\pm$2.76 & 9.37 $\pm$9.79 & 22.15 $\pm$24.88\\
Volume error    & 4.285 $\pm$0.6 & 15.75 $\pm$13.67 & 3.51 $\pm$2.74 & 11.96 $\pm$11.03 & 35.65 $\pm$40.28\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Hope it works as you want!

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you very much it exactly fixed my problem. I'll be more careful from now.

Comment: Don't say that! This type of errors can happen to everyone. Have a nice day `@Unic0`!

Comment: please fix `\begin{tabular}[h!]{ l c c c c }` `tabular` has no `h!` argument.

Comment: Done, `@David Carlisle`!

Answer (score 1):

Beside of the mistake in the number of columns and place the float options in the tabular environment, because the uneven number of integers and decimals in each cell, consider also use `siunitx` for a proper alignment:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{ table-number-alignment=center,
separate-uncertainty=true,
table-figures-uncertainty=1,
 table-figures-integer = 2,
 table-figures-decimal = 3}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption[Atrial segmentation: dataset LA regions score table]{Metrics score table for the different regions of the LA using LA cavity-endocardium labels. Abbreviations: LA, left atrium; MSD, mean surface distance; PV, pulmonary veins.}\label{endo_analysis_table}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{5}{S}@{}}
\toprule
 {Metrics} & {Overall} & {Mitral valve region} & {LA central region} & {PV region} & {LA roof}\\
 & & {(0-20\%)} & {(20-65\%)} & {(65-85\%)} & {(85-100\%)}\\
\midrule
Dice score & 93.77 \pm 0.17 & 88.38 \pm 7.3 & 96.01 \pm 1.43 & 89.60 \pm 5.15 & 78.75 \pm 12.13\\
Jacquard Index & 88.32 \pm 0.3 & 80.41 \pm 10.02 & 92.37 \pm 2.59 & 81.77 \pm 7.74 & 66.93 \pm 14.82\\
MSD & 0.613 \pm 0.02 & 1.534 \pm 1.01 & 0.875 \pm 0.37 & 1.571 \pm 1.17 & 1.841 \pm 1.44\\
Sensibility & 93.87 \pm 0.03 & 89 \pm 11.74 & 95.78 \pm 2.68 & 90.78 \pm 7.52 & 83.85 \pm 15.63\\
Specificity & 99.70 \pm 0.002 & 99.61 \pm 0.44 & 99.59 \pm 0.27 & 99.36 \pm 0.49 & 99.65 \pm 0.41\\
Diameter error & 3.277 \pm 1.1 & 11.31 \pm 9.42 & 2.81 \pm 2.76 & 9.37 \pm 9.79 & 22.15 \pm 24.88\\
Volume error & 4.285 \pm 0.6 & 15.75 \pm 13.67 & 3.51 \pm 2.74 & 11.96 \pm 11.03 & 35.65 \pm 40.28\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```